# How to verify if a user visiting a Blogspot blog is the owner of that blog?

Tags: html, blogspot

I would like to verify that the user is the owner of the blog by doing something like the following:

```
<b:if cond='is_admin'>
(display an admin button)
</b:if>
```

Any recommendations?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the answer is:

```
<b:if cond='data:post.editUrl'>
    <span expr:class='&quot;item-control &quot; + data:post.adminClass'>
        (display an admin button)
    </span>
</b:if>
```

I apologize for the inconvenience!

Thanks